# Tallit katan instead of tallit gadol when traveling

Tags: travel, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

If you're traveling and trying to pack lightly, can you pack tefillin and "just" a tallit katan? Can you rely on a tallit katan rather than a tallit gadol, even if you'd normally wear tallit gadol at home?

Comment: Hi Justin. It's hard to imagine how some random online person here could provide an answer with a general rule. As with many questions of leniencies in pressing circumstances, it will surely depend on the particular situation.

Comment: Is there normally a requirement to wear a tallit gadol?

Comment: @alex is ther normally a requirement to wear a tallis katan? If you do not have a 4 cornered garment, are you required to go get one or is it strongly reccomended?

Comment: @Chatzkel If the post had been about tallis katan I would indeed ask the same question.

Comment: That might depend whether one prays in a synagogue where one can buy a tallit gadol or alone. When traveling weekly for 20+ years, I had bought a shorter/lighter tallit gadol since I was trying to pack light, that might be a solution here as well

Comment: And [welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Justin with thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Halachicly wise sure, you Yotzeh of the Brocho on Tallis Katan too, wrapping the whole body in Tallis Godol is a Kabbalistic idea.

Comment: Thank you all, and glad to. be here!